# NServiceBus without MSDTC

Tags: nservicebus

I'm in the process of updating an existing application that currently can only be deployed on premise, but in the near future we also need to be able to deploy it on Azure. The current implementation uses MSDTC, but this is not supported on Azure. Is it possible to run NServiceBus without MSDTC when deploying it on premise? Or should I enable MSDTC when deploying on premise, but ignore it when deploying on Azure?

Is it even possible to run NServiceBus without MSDTC at all? If I configure NServiceBus like this:

```
.IsTransactional(false)
```

it still tries to start a distributed transaction. So I suppose MSDTC is always required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy NServiceBus to the cloud there is no MSMQ available for it to use. You can configure it to use Azure Storage Queues.

Because the underlying transport is so different I don't see any advantage disabling transactions in NSB on-premise as any behavior as a result of this may not transfer to the cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

MSDTC is required by default when using MSMQ. You can avoid DTC if you enable and configure the [outbox feature](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/)